# Simple JS to pick random quote not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a simple JS random quote generator using the html and JS code below. However, it is not returning any quotes. I am a newbie in JS. Appreciate any help on this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="https://abcd.com/wp-includes/js/quotes.js"></script>
<script>
showQuotation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS** 
(This is the code in https://abcd.com/wp-includes/js/quotes.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Copyright 2004 by CodeLifter.com
var Quotation=new Array()
Quotation[0] = "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.";
Quotation[1] = "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.";
Quotation[2] = "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.";
Quotation[3] = "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.";
Quotation[4] = "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.";
Quotation[5] = "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.";
Quotation[6] = "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.";
Quotation[7] = "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.";
Quotation[8] = "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.";
Quotation[9] = "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.";
var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();
</script>
```

Comment: When doing web development, it's essential to keep the dev tools open and look for errors in the web console, step through code in the built-in debugger, etc.

Comment: Also note that you're showing the quotation twice, once in `quotes.js` (at the end), and again later with inline script.

Comment: Use `Quotation[Math.floor(Math.random() * Quotation.length)]` for selecting a random quote. Otherwise the first and last element are each going to have half the probability of the other elements. Also, the variables `Q` and `whichQuotation` are pointless because they’re only used once. Also, [don’t use `document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212).

Comment: @Crowder Totally agree. This was just a one time activity I needed so did not bother to install any dev tools. But I do understand its importance. Also thanks for pointing out about showing the quotation twice. Corrected.

Comment: @ThomasKoipuram You don’t need to install anything. They’re right in your browser. [Here’s how to open them](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (simply hit `F12`).

Answer (score 0):

As per comments provided by all, I have modified my code as below. Let me know if its technically correct. From a requirement perspective, it is working as expected. Not sure if its the right way to convey it here (by posting an answer). If not, please let me know.

**HTML**

```
<p id="quotes-div"></p>
<script src="https://abcd.com/wp-includes/js/quotes.js">
</script>
```

**JS**
Code inside quotes.js

```
// Copyright 2004 by CodeLifter.com
var Quotation=
[
    "Time is of the essence! Comb your hair.",
    "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.",
    "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.",
    "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.",
    "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.",
    "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.",
    "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.",
    "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.",
    "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.",
    "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.",
];
function showQuotation()
{
    document.getElementById("quotes-div").innerHTML = Quotation[Math.floor(Math.random() * Quotation.length)]
}
showQuotation();
```

Comment: I have edited your answer to change the indentation of the Quotation definition, it should make things easier to read.